# Generate custom JSON with SQL

Tags: azure, databricks, databricks-sql

I’m trying to generate a JSON with unity catalog information. My desired output is:

```
table_name : {
     column1 : {
         type: column1type
    },
    column2 : {
         type: column2type
    },
    column3: {
         type: column3type
    },
    …
}
```

I tried the following SQL:

```
WITH column_metadata AS (
    SELECT
        COLUMN_NAME,
        DATA_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
)

SELECT
    TO_JSON(
        MAP(
            COLLECT_LIST(
                MAP(
                    COLUMN_NAME,
                    TO_JSON(MAP('type', DATA_TYPE))
                )
            )
        )
    ) AS json_result
FROM column_metadata
```

When I run the above SQL, I got the following error:

```
[INVALID_OPTIONS.NON_MAP_FUNCTION] Invalid options: Must use the `map()` function for options.
```

Why is this error happening since I'm using `MAP` in every `TO_JSON` function?

Comment: Yes, I’m using Databricks on Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any one of the query to get column name and type.

```
SELECT
    to_json(
        MAP(
            'table_name',
            collect_list(MAP(COLUMN_NAME,MAP('type', DATA_TYPE))
            )
        )
    ) AS json_result
FROM column_metadata
```

Output:

[image]

Or

```
SELECT
    to_json(
        MAP(
            'table_name',
            collect_list(struct(COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE)
            )
        )
    ) AS json_result
FROM column_metadata
```

Output:

[image]

Here instead of using `map` i used `struct` which create struct type data with the column name.